# Azure Active Directory - How to give an http redirectUri for my registered app under tenant

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have created a tenant under my organization and registered an app for my testing react application. I have deployed my react application in one of the kubrnetes http server. Is there a way to add http url (react application uri which deployed in kubernetes) in Redirect URI in app registration.

1. I have given SPA during app registration
2. Account type - Single tenant
3. Checked both access token and ID token

Comment: Yes!!! you can add redirect url from the portal, just go the Authentication tab.

Comment: Hello Manish, In Authentication tab I am able to add https requests, and http request with only localhost (development purpose). But when I deployed react app in one of my kubernetes, The URL will be http://****.amazonaws.com. This I couldn't add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redirect URIs must begin with the scheme https.

The HTTPS scheme (https://) is supported for all HTTP-based redirect URIs.
The HTTP scheme (http://) is supported only for localhost URIs and should be used only during active local application development and testing.

Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#supported-schemes) for more information

There is no other option available to use Http Schema.

Comment: Thanks @JayakrishnaGunnam. Even I didnt find a way to add http redirectUri. I was suppose to deploy a server with https protocol for this scenario. Thanks for the response.